# Need help transferring basemap to cartopy on python

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I need to recreate old code that plots Hurricane tracks. I've learned that Basemap no longer works with Python 3 so I need to use Cartopy to get this to work. Here's what I have. I believe my dataset is still good so here's where I call the lat and lon data to create the plots. If anyone could help me convert this, or provide any other advice I would greatly appreciate it.

```
m = Basemap(projection = 'mill', llcrnrlat = 22.5, urcrnrlat = 38, llcrnrlon = -110, urcrnrlon = -90, resolution = 'h')

x,y= m(ikelon,ikelat)
a,b= m(carlalon,carlalat)
c,d= m(beulahlon, beulahlat)
e,f= m(celialon, celialat)
g,h= m(allenlon, allenlat)
i,j= m(alicialon, alicialat)
k,l= m(gilbertlon, gilbertlat)
n,o= m(bretlon, bretlat)
p,q= m(ritalon, ritalat)
t,u= m(harveylonarray2, harveylatarray2)

m.plot(a,b,'go-', label='Carla, 1961')
m.plot(c,d,'bo-', label='Beulah, 1967')
m.plot(e,f,'yo-', label='Celia, 1970')
m.plot(g,h,'co-', label='Allen, 1980')
m.plot(i,j,'mo-', label='Alicia, 1983')
m.plot(k,l,'ko-', label='Gilbert, 1988')
m.plot(n,o,'o-', color='#9DFF5E', label='Bret, 1999')
m.plot(p,q,'o-', color='#F39C12', label='Rita, 2005')
m.plot(x,y,'ro-', label='Ike, 2008')
m.plot(t,u,'o-', color='#FF8CC2', label='Harvey, 2017')

m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawmapboundary()
plt.title('Texas Hurricanes Paths, 1950-2017')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please try to show some effort doing it by yourself. If you have trouble, and face a specific ploblem, then, you can post for help.

Comment: The Cartopy gallery has an example for plotting the track of Hurricane Katrina.  Perhaps you could adapt it https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/lines_and_polygons/hurricane_katrina.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-and-polygons-hurricane-katrina-py